# Не получается конвертировать str в int или float

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dollars = int(input())
# url = "https://select.by/kurs/"
# headers = {
#     "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
#     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
# }

# response = requests.get(url, headers)

# with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
#     file.write(response.text)

with open("index.html", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

exchange_rate = soup.find("td", class_="right-border")

string = ""
for i in exchange_rate:
    string += i

string = string.replace(",", ".")
print(dollars * int(string))
```

Ошибка выглядит таким образом:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\VsCode\learning\ParcingBYNtoUSD.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(dollars * int(string))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.6550'
```

Comment: Ну а что насчёт `float(string)`?

Comment: @andreymal я сейчас немного в шоке, потому что все точно проверил несколько раз и не работало. И как только хотел вызвать эту ошибку снова для вас, все заработало. Если я удалю этот вопрос, меня не зарепортят? А то два года назад был похожий случай

Comment: Строчки ``string = "" ``, ``for i in exchange_rate:    string += i`` можно заменить на ``string = exchange_rate``. Далее, т.к. никакого смысла в дополнительной переменной нет, то можно просто это все выбросить и написав ``string= soup.find("td", class_="right-border")`` получить нахаляву более короткий код.